# How to fix cors issue with node module the-noun-project (API wrapper) with create react app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, proxy, cors

I am stuck on this problem. I am using the node module https://www.npmjs.com/package/the-noun-project it works to a certain extent, I am using create react app. Here is my code so far. The error I am getting is below the code. Now I am used to using something like **cors anywhere** with **fetch** where I manually change the URL and use the cors anywhere proxy, but when I am using a separate node module I don't know how I would proxy it to cors because I can't change the code in the node_module itself, or if there is an alternate solution?

```
import React from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import NounProject from 'the-noun-project';

const nounProject = new NounProject({
    key: 'key',
    secret: 'secret'
});

console.log(nounProject);

nounProject.getIconsByTerm('goat', {limit: 5}, function (err, data) {
  if (!err) {
      console.log(data.icons);
  }
});

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <header className="App-header">
        <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
        <p>
          Edit <code>src/App.js</code> and save to reload.
        </p>
        <a
          className="App-link"
          href="https://reactjs.org"
          target="_blank"
          rel="noopener noreferrer"
        >
          Learn React
        </a>
      </header>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Error

> Access to fetch at 'https://api.thenounproject.com/icons/goat?limit=5' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

Comment: You’ll not be able to use that NounProject wrapper from frontend JavaScript code running in a browser. To be usable from frontend code, it would need to provide some way to make the requests through some form of proxy that adds the necessary CORS response headers. But it doesn’t expose anything like that, so there’s no way you’re gonna be able to use the wrapper in frontend code. If you want the features that the wrapper provides, you’d need to fork the code and write in some proxying mechanism yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Look here `https://github.com/rosshettel/the-noun-project/issues/9`, looks like the server you are accessing for this npm package doesnt have the correct CORS headers set. You will need to either route through an API or use a CORS blocker depending on your browser.

Comment: how would I route through an api? is there an example I can look at somewhere?